# ESLint warning - Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default

Tags: javascript, warnings, eslint

When I try to create and export an arrow function like this:

```
export default () => {};
```

I get this warning from ESLint:

> Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default

Of course i can assign it to a variable and then export it. But why can't i do it the other way?
What is wrong with exporting an arrow function without assigning it to something?

Comment: [Here is the rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md). As pretty much all ESLint rules, it includes the rationalisation. As with every single ESLint rule, you can choose change or ignore the rule.

Answer (score 16):

this will solve the issue:

```
const Name = () => {  }; 

export default Name
```

If you read eslint docs [es-lint docs](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.25.2/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md)

> Reports if a module's default export is unnamed. This includes several
> types of unnamed data types; literals, object expressions, arrays,
> anonymous functions, arrow functions, and anonymous class
> declarations.
>
> Ensuring that default exports are named helps improve the grepability
> of the codebase by encouraging the re-use of the same identifier for
> the module's default export at its declaration site and at its import
> sites.

**grepability:** grep is a command for finding things, based on patterns. grep-ability would be the use of certain programming conventions that make it easier to find information.

Answer (score 14):

It is not an Error. It is a Warning. So you CAN do it. However, it is not good practice.

Here's the thing: when you say `() => {}`, you're declaring an anonymous function with no name. When you say `var foo = function() {}` you are declaring an anonymous function, then assigning it as the value to the `foo` variable.

It's a small difference, but it matters if you care about writing code that is easy to reuse and debug.

When you **name the function** your debugger is able to label it correctly for you in the debugging pane, but if you declare an anonymous function you'll just see anonymous function. This can be a pain when debugging, so by putting in a little repetitive effort when it's easy (when you name it) you can potentially save yourself (or other people who get to read/use your code) a headache later when debugging.

If you are sure what you do is exporting anonymous functions, ESLint's docs tell you [how to disable the error notification](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.24.2/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md):

```
"import/no-anonymous-default-export": ["error", {
  "allowArray": false,
  "allowArrowFunction": false,
  "allowAnonymousClass": false,
  "allowAnonymousFunction": false,
  "allowCallExpression": true, // The true value here is for backward compatibility
  "allowLiteral": false,
  "allowObject": false
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:
export default () => {... };

Use this:
const function = () => { ... };
export default function;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A bit of formatting always nice, but thanks for your answer, and welcome.